# Is there a way to call Stored Procedure From Spring Boot with CLOB as input parameter?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here is my scenario. We have a stored procedue  SP_SAVE_RJ_INSTANCE(?, ?, ?), the first parameter is CLOB input parameter , second out put parameter number, third out put parameter varchar.

I tried below approches both are not working out.

```
@Transactional
    public void callStoredProcedure(String data) {
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.doWork(connection -> {        try (CallableStatement function = connection.prepareCall(
                "{ call SP_SAVE_RJ_INSTANCE(?, ?, ?) }")) {
            Clob clobData = connection.createClob();
            clobData.setString(1, data);
            function.setClob(1, clobData);
            function.registerOutParameter(2, Types.NUMERIC);
            function.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
            ResultSet resultSet = function.executeQuery();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // handle exception
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }
        });
    }
--------------------------------- NamedStoredProcedure way---------
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "ComOwnerSeqEntity.sp_save_rj_instance",
        procedureName = "COM_OWNER.COM_PKG.sp_save_rj_instance", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "RJCOMMONDATAIN", type = Clob.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "O_REQUESTID", type = Number.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "O_ALTREQUESTID", type = String.class)})

-----------------------------------------

Tried calling from repostiory

@Repository
public interface ComOwnerRepository extends JpaRepository<ComOwnerSeqEntity, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT TRACORE_OWNER.CORRECTION_REQUEST_SEQ.nextval FROM dual", nativeQuery = true)
    public Long getNextValMySequence();

    @Procedure(name = "ComOwnerSeqEntity.sp_save_rj_instance")
   public Map<String, Object> getAlternateID(String RJCOMMONDATAIN);
}
```

---

Comment: What error message do you get and did you try with a char[] as parameter?